# Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android-activity, android-fragments

I am getting two Errors in my Code.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.dfoley.write_to_file.topFragment did not create a view.

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment both pointing to Line MainActivity.java:21 which is the following  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

bottomFragment

```
package com.example.dfoley.write_to_file;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class bottomFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ArrayAdapter<StateUser> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        ArrayList<StateUser> flight = MainContoller.getInstance().getFlights();
        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<StateUser>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, flight);
        setListAdapter(this.adapter);
        super.onActivityCreated(saveInstanceState);
    }
    public void refreshList(){
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Top Fragment

```
package com.example.dfoley.write_to_file;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import.android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import.android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;



public class topFragment extends Fragment{
    private FlightSearcher searcher;
    EditText text1;

    public interface FlightSearcher {
        public void refreshFlightList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        searcher = (FlightSearcher) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setupListeners();
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setupListeners() {
        Button addUser = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
        addUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                writeToFile();
                searcher.refreshFlightList();
            }
        });
    }

    private void writeToFile() {
        text1=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String AddUsers = text1.getText().toString();
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(getActivity().openFileOutput("UserList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(AddUsers);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
package com.example.dfoley.write_to_file;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements topFragment.FlightSearcher{

    public void refreshFlightList() {
        FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();
        bottomFragment bottomFragmentRef =(bottomFragment) mgr.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_fragment);
        bottomFragmentRef.refreshList();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activiy_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.dfoley.write_to_file.topFragment"
    android:id="@+id/top_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/topfragment" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.dfoley.write_to_file.bottomFragment"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/bottomfragment" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both of your fragments, you are not telling it how to create a view. I see that you are using the tools:layout tag, but according to the Tools doc, that is only a hint to the designer; it does not actually inflate that layout:

"This attribute is typically set in a  tag and is used to record which layout you want to see rendered at designtime (at runtime, this will be determined by the actions of the fragment class listed by the tag)."

Thus you need to override onCreateView, inflate your view hierarchy, and then return that:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.topfragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Hello, where should we add this method. I do not have a class that extends fragment. Just a fragmentActivity I have, but still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 4):

Change fragment to FrameLayout

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```