# Binary XML file line #9 : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm unable to figure out why I'm getting this error. Below is my code:

View.java

---

```
public class View extends FragmentActivity {

public static final String tview = "View";
Context context;


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    try
    {
       context = this;
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.view_1);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(tview, ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

ViewArrayAdapter.java

---

```
public class ViewArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private ArrayList<String>  values;

public ViewArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values)
{
    super(context, R.layout.listview, values);
    this.context= context;
    this.values=values; 
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label12);
    CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox12);
    textView.setText(values.get(position));
    return rowView;
}

}
```

---

ViewFragment.java

---

```
public class ViewFragment extends ListFragment{
public static final String tview = "View1";
Context context;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
           ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_fragment, 
            container, false);

            try
            {


            ArrayList<String> list = getViewList();
            setListAdapter(new ViewArrayAdapter(getActivity(), list));
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e(tview, ex.getMessage());
            }
             return view;
       }

private ArrayList<String> getViewList()
{
List<Vector> list = new ArrayList<Vector>();

File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File sdImageMainDirectory1 = new File(root, "/java/");

String file_path = sdImageMainDirectory1.toString() + "/applicants.txt";
String entireFile = "";

try
{
    BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_path));

    try {
        String line = br.readLine();

        while(line!=null)
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,"|");
            int count=0;
            String tok1="", tok2="", tok3="";
            Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                switch(count){
                case 0:
                    tok1 = st.nextToken();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tok2 = st.nextToken();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tok3 = st.nextToken();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            vec.add(tok1);
            vec.add(tok2);
            vec.add(tok3);
            list.add(vec);
            line=br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(tview, "error while reading applicants.txt!");
    }
}catch (Exception e) 
{
    Log.e(tview, "error while initializing applicants.txt!");

}

ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
int i=0;
while(i<list.size()){
    String mystring = list.get(i).elementAt(0).toString() + " ";
    mystring +=list.get(i).elementAt(1).toString() + " "; 
    mystring +=list.get(i).elementAt(2).toString() + " "; 
    mylist.add(mystring);
    i++;
}

return mylist;
}

}
```

---

listview.xml

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp" >

<CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/chkbox12"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp">
 </CheckBox>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

view_1.xml

---

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/view" />

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/view_fragment"
    class="com.example.test.ViewFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

---

view.xml

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="620dp"
 android:background="#ffffffff"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/layout">

 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" android:text="TEST"
    android:background="#614767"
    android:textSize="32sp" 
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    />

   <ImageView
        android:layout_height="46dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/logo_web" 
        android:id="@+id/logo" 
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

---

view_fragment.xml

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/chkbox121"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp">
 </CheckBox>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label121"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

logcat messages

---

```
    04-25 01:48:40.680: E/View(7473): Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

    04-25 01:48:40.681: W/System.err(7473): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
    04-25 01:48:40.682: W/System.err(7473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    04-25 01:48:40.683: W/System.err(7473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    04-25 01:48:40.683: W/System.err(7473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    04-25 01:48:40.683: W/System.err(7473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    04-25 01:48:40.683: W/System.err(7473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    04-25 01:48:40.683: W/System.err(7473):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
    04-25 01:48:40.684: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
    04-25 01:48:40.684: W/System.err(7473):     at com.example.test.View.onCreate(View.java:56)
    04-25 01:48:40.684: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    04-25 01:48:40.684: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    04-25 01:48:40.684: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    04-25 01:48:40.685: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    04-25 01:48:40.685: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    04-25 01:48:40.685: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    04-25 01:48:40.685: W/System.err(7473):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-25 01:48:40.685: W/System.err(7473):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    04-25 01:48:40.685: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    04-25 01:48:40.686: W/System.err(7473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    04-25 01:48:40.686: W/System.err(7473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    04-25 01:48:40.686: W/System.err(7473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    04-25 01:48:40.686: W/System.err(7473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    04-25 01:48:40.686: W/System.err(7473): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
    04-25 01:48:40.688: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
    04-25 01:48:40.688: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
    04-25 01:48:40.689: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
    04-25 01:48:40.689: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
    04-25 01:48:40.689: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1147)
    04-25 01:48:40.690: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2116)
    04-25 01:48:40.690: W/System.err(7473):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5328)
    04-25 01:48:40.690: W/System.err(7473):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
    04-25 01:48:40.690: W/System.err(7473):     ... 20 more
```

---

Can someone please help me in identifying what I' doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Check this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906418/binary-xml-file-line-11-error-inflating-class-fragment

Comment: please post the entire log cat message

Comment: added logcat messages

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to fix this error. Below are the changes I made to the code

ViewFragment.java

---

```
public class ViewFragment extends ListFragment{
public static final String tview = "View1";
Context context;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      ArrayList<String> list = getViewList();
      ViewArrayAdapter adapter = new       ViewArrayAdapter(getActivity(), list);
      setListAdapter(adapter);  
}
}
```

---

view_fragment.xml

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           />
```

---